# How to use theming in other module

Tags: theming

Currently I am building a module by reusing the 'page callback' function in an other module. The data array are successfully rendered. However The presentation is poor.

I suspect that after page callback it doesn't successfully load the theme (probably css?), but I don't know how to do that.

------update------

Here is the code. I add node_add_page from node module to a new menu named 'node/add/add-art'. The data is rendered successfully, however the format is broken. Is it possible to not only reuse the data process function, but also reuse the theme it is using?

```
$items['node/add/add-art'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add art work',
  'parent' => 'admin/commerce/manage-products/actions',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK | MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'page callback' => 'node_add_page',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
  'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
);
```

Comment: Would you mind posting some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the drupal_get_form() to render the node form.
For **art** content type.

```
$items['node/add/add-art'] = array(
  'title' => 'Add art work',
  'parent' => 'admin/commerce/manage-products/actions',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK | MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('art_node_form'),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'file' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc'
);
```